# Efficiently Fetching Multiple Images from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, image

My app will have lists of images like shown in the below example:

[image]

To fetch an individual image from firebase, I defined a `ViewModel` class with the single image as a `UIImage` property. The appropriate view can then update with published changes to this `ViewModel`. With several--and in fact an arbitrary amount--of images in a list, I don't imagine that giving each one its own `ViewModel` will be efficient, especially because I imagine that I'll have to `ForEach` to loop through each image reference and create a `ViewModel` inside the parent view. This seems problematic because whenever the parent view is recreated I'm doing an O(n) operation to create and initialize view models for each image, not to mention the time it takes to re-fetch.

Is there a way to fetch multiple images from inside one `ViewModel`, storing them as `[UIImage]`? I would presumbably give this `ViewModel` an array of references. Alternatively, what architecture would you suggest to efficiently fetch any number of images from firebase given an array (of unknown size) of storage references?

I can provide more detail / code as needed.

This seems to work...

```
class MultipleImageFetcher: ObservableObject {
    var firebaseManager: FirebaseManager
    var imageDictionary: [String: UIImage] = [:]
    @Published var isReady = false


    init(_ firebaseManager: FirebaseManager) {
        self.firebaseManager = firebaseManager
    }

    func fetchAllImages(references: [String]) {
        for refID in references {
            fetchIndividualImage(id: refID, totalNum: 
    references.count)
        }
    }

    func fetchIndividualImage(id: String, totalNum: Int) {
        let ref = getRefURL(uid: id)
        ref.getData(maxSize: 2051240) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
                return
            }
            self.imageDictionary[id] = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.checkIsReady(num: totalNum)
        }
    }

    func getRefURL(uid: String) -> StorageReference {
        return firebaseManager.STORAGE.reference().child(uid)
    }

    func checkIsReady(num: Int) {
        if imageDictionary.count == num {
            self.isReady = true
        } else {
            self.isReady = false
        }
    }
}



struct ImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetcher: MultipleImageFetcher

    init(_ firebaseManager: FirebaseManager) {
        self.fetcher = MultipleImageFetcher(firebaseManager)
    }


    var body: some View {

        Button {
            fetcher.fetchAllImages(references: 
["KXKFM94sk5OTyld2VsCQdhijd6m1", "MtgRaKMwyQfYX2uxuHs3iH3pLB52"])
        } label: {
            Text("Load Image")
        }

        if fetcher.isReady {
            Text("Is Ready")
        } else {
            Text("Loading...")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can definitely fetch multiple images in one view model and yes, you could store them as `[UIImage]`, but realistically, you'll probably want to store them as a key/value pair so that you know what cell they belong to. In other words, `[UUID:UIImage]` or something like that. You may also want to look into cacheing the results (`NSCache`?)

Comment: What kind of function call do I make to Firebase? I imagine there's more to it then `ref.getData()` but in a for loop...

And yes, caching is definately on my mind...

Comment: No, there's not really much more to it then that -- there is if you care *when* the data gets back (meaning something sequential has to happen).

Comment: Ok, I'll play around with that approach

Comment: Take a look at this...

Comment: My only worry is what to do in case one of my individual images fails to load. right now that would stop all of them, though I don't want to show a blank screen either...

Comment: I suggest you look into Combine -- it is going to be a more robust solution for loading a pipeline and handling errors